# How do I add TextDecoration(s) to a DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I successfully added my multiple dropdowns, but I want an InputDecoration as per a TextFormField, so I can keep the user interface consistent, and show what the dropdown was after you've selected from the drop down.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Action'
  ),
);
```

Apparently I need 10 reputation to post images. (I mean it makes sense)

[TextFormField with labelText set to Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouI5E.png)

Gives me a nice looking TextFormField... But I want the same type of interface for my dropdown, where i can give it an InputDecoration.  Now I want the same 'labelText' above my DropdownButton after I've selected it.

[My DropdownButton has a nice look and feel before I've entered the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2o99.png)

[But afterwards it doesn't have a reminder for what the dropdown was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z324H.png)

[I was hoping for something along these lines, but even this quickly edited version has a smaller space between the line and the selected text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfHXq.png)

I tried creating a mixin of the TextDecorator/TextDecoration and put it into the existing DropdownButton class, but I am still super noob at the language and just learnt about mixins and it doesn't seem like it would help.  How would I go about adding the TextDecoration from a TextFormField onto a DropdownButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you could use
[DropdownButtonFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html)
Doing something like this :

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Action'),
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('Action1')),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('Action2'),)
  ],
  onChanged: (value){
    print(value);
  },
),
```

Comment: OMG thanks, it's so simple! Just what I was hoping for!